# Search files and folders in dropbox API

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am developing a application that will show all the files and folders in the web page. I have done this. 
Now i am trying to add search filter for that.
I have searched in google. But not getting expected result.

I have completed getting the accessToken from credential.

```
$client = new Dropbox\Client($_SESSION['accessToken'],parent::$appName,'UTF-8');
```

From this I am getting all the files. 
How to pass the search file names or folder names here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass the file names or folder names in the Dropbox\Client.

There is separate function([**searchFileNames**](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_searchFileNames)) to pass the `path`,`query string`. 
If you pass the parameter that will return the files and folder.

```
$client = new Dropbox\Client($_SESSION['accessToken'],parent::$appName,'UTF-8');

$foldername=isset($foldername)?$foldername:'';
$dropbox_file=$client->searchFileNames('/'.$foldername,$search);
```

if you print the $dropbox_file you can see the files and folders.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dropbox_file);
echo '</pre>';
```

For more functions you can check [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/Dropbox/Client.php)

Comment: please check this?

Comment: Note that this [Dropbox PHP SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/php) uses API v1 which is [deprecated and being retired soon](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should switch to [API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead, e.g., using one of [these libraries](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks).